# Unity tweak tool install problem - can't install all the dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies, unity-tweak-tool

When I try to install `unity-tweak-tool` I get this message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-tweak-tool : Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried to install unity-webapps-common and I got this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-webapps-common : Depends: unity-webapps-service (>= 2.3.8-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried to install `unity-webapps-service` and I got this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-webapps-service : Depends: webapp-container
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And when I try to install `webapp-container` I get stuck at this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 webapp-container : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
                    Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0
                    Depends: liboxideqt-qmlplugin (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: qml-module-ubuntu-web (= 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin (>= 1.3) or
                             qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles (>= 1.3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: unity-webapps-qml but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: webbrowser-app (= 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I really can't figure out this last one. What is the problem here?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are yours? What if you type `sudo apt -f install`?

Comment: @Redbob `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS x86_64 `.   `sudo apt -f install` gives me `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 221 not upgraded.
`

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792837/issues-with-unity-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu-16-04)?

Comment: @Redbob with aptitude i  installed successfully unitx-tweak-tool., but program is not looking same as one installed via apt-get.  Anyway, 
it will serve the purpose.